# Draw the plane on ParametricPlot3D with one parameter

Tags: plotting

I need to make semitransparent coordinate plane(s) at `ParametricPlot3D` with one parameter. If I add the second parameter the curves becomes ugly.

```
 GraphicsRow[{
   ParametricPlot3D[{
     {Sin[u], Tan[u], u/10}, 
     0.5 {Cos[u], Sin[u], u/10}}, 
   {u, -20, 20},  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}], 
   ParametricPlot3D[{
     {Sin[u], Tan[u], u/10}, 
     0.5 {Cos[u], Sin[u], u/10}, 
     {u/10, v/10, 0}}, 
  {u, -20, 20}, {v, -20, 20}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]}]
```

[image]

[image]

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make two separate graphics and combine them using `Show`

```
Show[{ParametricPlot3D[{{Sin[u], Tan[u], u/10}, 
    0.5 {Cos[u], Sin[u], u/10}}, {u, -20, 20}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{u/10, v/10, 0}, {u, -20, 20}, {v, -20, 20}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.3, Magenta]}]}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

In versions 10+, you can use `InfinitePlane`:

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{{Sin[u], Tan[u], u/10}, 0.5 {Cos[u], Sin[u], u/10}}, {u, -20, 20}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}], 
 Graphics3D@{Opacity[.3, Blue], InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}]}]
```

[image]